# Unique database entry determined by attributes

Tags: python, django, class, model, unique

I have the following class:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and I make two identical instances of this class:

```
alex_1 = Person(name='Alex', age=30)
alex_1.save()
alex_2 = Person(name='Alex', age=30)
alex_2.save()
```

This will save 2 entries in the person database. Is there any way to prevent the second instance (`alex_2`) from being saved as it's technically a duplicate? i.e., can you implement the `__eq__` and `__hash__` functions for `models.Model` instances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can use a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) over a *combination* of the fields:

```
from django.db.models.constraints import UniqueConstraint

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'age'], name='person_unique')
        ]
```

This thus means that the *combination* of `name` and `age` values should be unique. So `Person(name='Alex', age=30)` and `Person(name='Alex', age=40)` will not raise an error, but two objects `Person(name='Alex', age=30)` and `Person(name='Alex', age=30)` will result in an error, like:

> ```
> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'Alex-30' for key 'person_unique'")
> ```

Before [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can use [**`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['name', 'age']
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Will this stop the second instance from being saved then?

Comment: @alex_lewis: yes, normally it will raise an `IntegrityError` for the second insertion, it is usually enforced at db level.

Comment: Cool, you clarified that just as I posted the comment. I'll accept shortly .... Thanks again

Comment: @alex_lewis: yes that is correct, it is probably indeed better to include it in the code sample, thanks :).

Comment: good answer, upvoted. I think the unique_together should be `unique_together = (['name', 'age'],)`

Comment: @BradMartsberger: Django made an extra functionality for a single list "*For convenience, `unique_together` can be a single list when dealing with a single set of fields*" (ref. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

Comment: @BradMartsberger: If you however want to add multiple ones, it is indeed `unique_together = [['foo', 'bar'], ['foo', 'qux']]` for example.